# How to use the newer version git as the default?

Tags: git

I have two git in my CentOS-7.2 now.

```
[root@www bin]# /usr/bin/git --version
git version 1.8.3.1
[root@www bin]# /usr/local/git/bin/git --version
git version 2.9.5
```

I use the `git` it default is `git 1.8.3.1` this one.

I want to use the `git` default as the this one `/usr/local/git/bin/git`.

How can I remove the `/usr/bin/git` and use the new version one?

I tried use the:

```
echo "export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/git/bin" >> /etc/bashrc
source /etc/bashrc
```

But the `git` default still is `git 1.8.3.1`, how can I realize my requirement?

Should I delete the old version one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the folder first:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/git/bin:$PATH
```

Then the new Git would show up.

But an alternative way would be:

```
mv /usr/bin/git /usr/bin/git.v1.8.2
ln -s /usr/local/git /usr/bin/git
```

Answer (score 1):

try running this command

```
update-alternatives --set git /usr/local/git/bin/git
```

it wont remove the `/usr/bin/git` but when you run `git` in terminal it will point to `/usr/local/git/bin/git`